# Ratio , proportion question

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

> It will take 24 men working 9 hours a day each of build a house in 45 days . Given that all men work at the same rate,
>
> (A) how many days will 18 men take to build the same house if they work 8 hours a day?
>
> (B) how many hours per day must 20 men work if the house is to be completed in 48 days?

I'm having my mid-year examinations tomorrow and this question will be coming out. This is always my stumbling block as I don't understand the steps I need to take to solve this problem. Can I get any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the "efficiency" of their work:
$$e= \frac{H}{M\times D\times \frac{T}{24}}$$

$H$ - number of houses built

 $M$ - men working

 $D$ - days taken

 $T$ - hours per day

---

Thus, we calculate $e$ first:

$$e= \frac{1}{24\times 45\times \frac{9}{24}}$$
$$e=\frac{1}{405} $$

Now you just plug in the data you got and use your calculated $e$.

$A)$
$$ \frac{1}{405}=\frac{1}{18\times D \times \frac{8}{24}}$$ 
$$405= 6D$$
$$D=67.5$$

I think you can do $B)$ for yourself now.

Answer (score 2):

Total men-hour-days required = 24*9*45
A) men = 18 , hour = 8 days = d = ?
so 18*8*d = 24*9*45
d = 24*9*45/18*8 =67.5 days

B) men = 20, d = 48 , h = ?
so 20*48*h = 24*9*45
h = 45*9/20*2 = 405/40 hours = 10 hour 7.5 minutes per day

For more such concepts you can look at https://www.handakafunda.com/how-to-solve-time-work-problems-in-cat/

Answer (score 1):

B) Man-hours to build the house = 24*9*45 = 9720

let x = hours per day 20 men must work

20*x*48 = 9720

x= 9720/(20*48)= 10.125 hrs/day